# How to get all the values from the same Name xml c#

Tags: c#, xml

My purpose is to make a program that creates a new file destination that takes some values from another file.
The XML file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <house>
  <chairs count="3">
  <chairs>a</chairs>
  <chairs>b</chairs>
  <chairs>c</chairs>
  </chairs>
 </house>
```

What I've done:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("file.xml"))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.IsStartElement())
                {
                    switch (reader.Name)
                    {

                        case "chairs":

                            if (reader.Read())
                            {
                                string l;
                                l = reader.Value.Trim();
                                //(*)
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

  // (**)f = l + " ";
```

If I write at the * line :

```
 Console.WriteLine(l), it will print me:

 a
 b
 c
```

But if I delete the (*) and I uncomment the (**), in the new created file it only shows c because I think it overrides the a and b because of concatenation.
It is possible to take all the values a,b,c and to write in the file, not only the last value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   List<string> strings = new List<string>();
   using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("file.xml"))
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.IsStartElement())
            {
                switch (reader.Name)
                {

                    case "chairs":

                        if (reader.Read())
                        {
                            strings.Add(reader.Value.Trim());
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This way the list `strings` will have all the nodes in it and can be used as a collection. You could concatenate if you wanted but the assignment in the initial code would suggest you are merely overwriting the value each time.

Comment: Thank you. Your idea helped me.

Answer (score 1):

There are number of ways you can do that.

- using simple iteration over XmlReader as you did
- [using XPath/XQuery query (`XmlDocument.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("\\chairs")`)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d271ytdx(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [using Linq2Xml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387041.aspx)
- using Linq2Xml with Xpath

but one of the most convinient ways of working with XMLs (when you know schema in advance) is to use [XSD.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.110).aspx) and generate classes for your schema, and then just [deserialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document) your xml to classes and work with C# classes.